# Getting No "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" Error when posting from firebase hosting to firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions, cors

I have a `post` function from firebase cloud functions, then, when I send the post request from my react app (hosted on firebase hosting), the console returns the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://asia-east2-example.cloudfunctions.net/api/something' from origin 'https://example.firebaseapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

and also this:

```
POST https://asia-east2-example.cloudfunctions.net/api/something net::ERR_FAILED
```

I have read some of the other stackoverflow questions but I don't really understand them.

**index.js** (firebase functions)

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const firebase = require("firebase");
const app = require("express")();
const cors = require("cors")({ origin: true });

const config = {
  apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  authDomain: "xampleee.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://example.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "example",
  storageBucket: "example.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "1111111111111",
  appId: "1:1111111111111:web:1111111111111",
  measurementId: "X-XXXXXXXXXXX",
};

admin.initializeApp();
firebase.initializeApp(config);

...

app.post("/response", (req, res) => {
  // cors(req, res, () => {
  let name = "";
  if (req.body.name !== null && req.body.name !== undefined) {
    name = req.body.name;
  } else {
    name = "anonymous";
  }

  const newResponse = {
    answer: req.body.answer,
    answerNames: req.body.answerNames,
    user: name,
    dateAnswered: new Date().toISOString(),
  };

  admin
    .firestore()
    .collection("Responses")
    .add(newResponse)
    .then((doc) => {
      const resResponse = newResponse;
      resResponse.responseId = doc.id;
      res.json(resResponse);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).json({
        error: "Something went wrong",
      });
      console.error(err);
    });
  // });
});

...

exports.api = functions.region("asia-east2").https.onRequest(app);
```

**firebase.json**

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
            "value": "*"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^7.15.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "./",
  "proxy": "https://asia-east2-example.cloudfunctions.net/api"
}
```

I will be happy to clarify anything unclear, and also to include more code as per requested. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*I have read some of the other stackoverflow questions but I don't really understand them.*" - you might want to edit the question to explain a bit about what exactly you read and why it was confusing.  Because your question here is probably just a duplicate of those other questions, and will get closed as a duplicate unless you explain why the problem here is different.  It looks like you started to implement the cors module in your code, then commented it out.  Why?

Comment: @DougStevenson I was trying to test it out, I don't really understand if I should implement the cors module or not, whether if it's useful. I want to ask if there are any ways that I can post content from a firebase hosted webpage to firestore.Cuz it seems like some of the other posts are just trying to solve the cors problem for `localhost` but not for the actual website. Since if there is a cors problem in the actual website, users will not able to use the functions.

Comment: You do need something implementing cors on your backend, and I suggest starting with the cors module documentation.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable CORS for your Cloud Functions.

You should import the npm cors library like this:

```
const cors = require("cors");
```

Then, you also need to make your express app use it with:

```
app.use(cors());
```

See the npm cors library [reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuration-options) for further cors configuration options